# how to add data to a certain fire-base child array by locating a item with in the array

Tags: java, arrays, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a firebase database. the data base structure is something like this.

```
Mainparent
  |

employees
  | 

employee_1
  |

name  
 Joe Bloggs

clock-on    (Data to add when button is clicked)
```

i want is to find the name child and add the clock on data to it. my java code i use the name-child and add it to a listview with in my app which then can be selected.

```
  mRootRef = new Firebase("my firebase url");
    final ListView elv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvnames);
    mRootRef.child("employees").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            final ArrayAdapter jlistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, webstreamsArray);


 elv.setAdapter(jlistAdapter);
  final String streamname = dataSnapshot.child("Fullname").getValue(String.class) ;
  jlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            webstreamsArray.add(streamname);
            elv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                   // **here i want to add the required data to my clockon-child. how do i add it to just the name selected from the list**
                      }
            });
```

How can i add the clock on data to just the selected name as at the moment it added its own child under the main parent. sorry if this sounds confusing lol.

Answer (score 0):

what i ended up doing is setting up fire base auth. then it would give the user a Uid. i asigned that id to there database file instead of employee_1 i now have there id.

next i told my app to look for a firebase user and got an instance of this called user then used user to find the id

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    String userid = user.getUid().toString();

String clockonstring = tvClock.getText().toString();
                    mrootRef.child("Employees").child(userid).child("clockontime").setValue(clockonstring);
```